# Converting coordinates into Longitude/Latatitude form that CartoDB understands?

Tags: carto, latitude-longitude

Does anyone know how to convert this infomation into longitude/latitude coordinates for georeferencing on cartodb?

```
UTC: Posn: 03:00N – 105:10E
LT: Posn: 01:28.0S – 116:48.0E
LT: Posn: 08:44.7S - 013:17.9E
```

These data represent locations in the middle of oceans.

Is there a simple rule/website for conversion?

Comment: I expect these are degrees:minutes so the first coordinate pair is latitude:3.0, longitude:105.16667, then -1.4667 116.8 and so on.

Comment: @mkennedy can you show me how you do the conversion?

Comment: Divide the second number by 60. A W or S means a negative number.

Comment: So LT: Posn: 08:44.7S - 013:17.9E would be 8.745 13.29833333?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to use a desktop software like a spreadsheet LibreOffice Calc or Microsoft Excel to process your data but if you really want to go the SQL way, this query parses a table with a field like yours and returns back a geometry. You will need a bit more of tuning for your use case but generally speaking this should work:

```
  WITH 
  data as (SELECT input_field FROM mytable),
  splitted as (
    SELECT 
      regexp_matches(
        data.input,
        '.*Posn:(.*):(.*)([S|N]).* - (.*):(.*)([E|W]).*'
      ) as data from data),
  coordinates as (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN data[3] ilike 'S' THEN
            (data[1]::numeric + data[2]::numeric/60.0) * -1
        ELSE data[1]::numeric + data[2]::numeric/60.0
        END as LAT,
        CASE WHEN data[6] ilike 'W' THEN
            (data[4]::numeric + data[5]::numeric/60.0) * -1
        ELSE data[4]::numeric + data[5]::numeric/60.0
        END as LON
    FROM splitted
  )
  SELECT 
    ST_AsText(
        CDB_LatLng(lat,lon)
      )
  FROM coordinates
```

First WITH clause is to get the data, second to split the input text into an array with the interesting components, third to convert them into lat/lon coordinates and the final one to generate the geometry.

Comment: Can you show me how you use Microsoft Excel to convert the data?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used Excel in ages, but the workflow should be similar to the one I posted: split the information into the pieces that give you the lat/lon and then perform the same calculation: degees + minutes/60.

Comment: So to get lat/lon, I need to first get the sum of degress and minutes and then divide the sum by 60?

Comment: Do I need to include a negative '-' sign when it is A or W?

Comment: No, it's degrees + (minutes / 60). Then if it's West (W) or South (S) you need to make it negative

Comment: So LT: Posn: 08:44.7S - 013:17.9E would be 8.745(lat) -13.29833333(lon)?

Comment: Yep, the result for the SQL is `POINT(13.2983333333333 -8.745)` being the first the longitude and the second the latitude